# How to configure Entity Framework with given conventions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have an MVC4 project with the DB (Sql2008) and Models (C#) already created, so it is not possible to change names on neither of them. I started using EF4.1 with custom configuration for each class I am using, so on model creating everything gets mapped to the database. Mostly all tables have name "tbl_X_" + entityName with primary keys entityName + "*ID". Others have "tbl*" + entityName and other primary keys. To avoid repeating code I created a custom EntityTypeConfiguration:

```
    public abstract class BaseConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T>
        where T: class
    {
        public BaseConfiguration()
        {
            Map(x => x.ToTable("tbl_X_" + typeof(T).Name));

            var parm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), typeof(T).Name);
            var propExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>
                (Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(parm, "Id"), typeof(int)), parm);
            Property(propExpression).HasColumnName(typeof(T).Name + "_ID");
        }
    }
```

This works fine for most of the cases except when the table name does not follow that convention and I map the table with its given name:

```
    public class CompanyConfiguration : BaseConfiguration<Company>
    {
        public CompanyConfiguration()
        {
            Map(x => x.ToTable("tbl_Company"));
            //Key does follow convention
        }
    }
```

When I build I get the error

> "Properties for type 'Company' can only be mapped once."

I am absolutly aware this happens cause I am mapping twice, one on base and the other on the derived class. What I want to know if it is possible to override the first if there is a second mapping for both tableName and primaryKeyName.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Some entities need discrimination.**

```
Map(x => x.Requires("discriminatorColumn")
                            .HasValue(value)
                            .HasColumnType("dataType")
                            .IsRequired())
                            .ToTable("tbl_TableName");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appreciated answers, yet not filling all requirements. This is the solution I have gotten so far:

I moved all table and primaryKey mappings to the BaseConfiguration class:

```
public class BaseConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T>
    where T : class
{
    public BaseConfiguration()
    {
        TableNameConvention();
        PrimaryKeyConvention();
    }

    private void TableNameConvention()
    {
        switch (typeof(T).Name)
        {
            case "entityA":
                ToTable("vw_entityA");
                break;
            case "entityB":
                ToTable("tbl_entityB");
                break;
            case "entityC":
                Map(x => x.Requires("discriminatorColumn")
                        .HasValue(value)
                        .HasColumnType("dataType")
                        .IsRequired())
                        .ToTable("tblentityC");
                break;

            default:
                ToTable("tbl_X_" + typeof(T).Name);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void PrimaryKeyConvention()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var parm = Expression.Parameter(type, type.Name);
        var propExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>
                (Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(parm, "Id"), typeof(int)), parm);

        switch (type.Name)
        {
            case "entityB":
                Property(propExpression).HasColumnName("IdEntityB");
                break;
            default:

                Property(propExpression).HasColumnName(type.Name + "_ID");

                break;
        }

    }



}
```

Then on my custom configuration classes I only map other columns, foreing keys, relationships. e.g.:

```
    public class EntityXConfiguration : BaseConfiguration<EntityX>
    {
        public EntityXConfiguration ()
        {
            ////Not needed here anymore. Moved to baseconfiguration
            //Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("EntityX_ID");
            //ToTable("tbl_X_EntityX");
            ////


            Property(x => x.ParentId).HasColumnName("EntityXParent_ID");
            Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("EntityXName");


            Ignore(x => x.EntityXProperty);

            ////Other mappings...
        }
    }
```

Feel free to add your comments!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The constructor on BaseConfiguration is always going to run before the constructor of CompanyConfiguration so there will always be a map action executed before the code block of CompanyConfiguration is run.  I am not aware of anyway of overriding the map call to allow it to be called a second time.  However, one option to solve this could be to have some overloaded constructors that resolve this.

Something like child class:

```
public class CompanyConfiguration : BaseConfiguration<Company>
{
    private readonly string customTableMap = "tbl_Company"; 

    public CompanyConfiguration() : base(customTableMap) { }
}
```

and on the parent :

```
public abstract class BaseConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T>
    where T: class
{
    private readonly string defaultTableMap = "tbl_X_" + typeof(T).Name;

    public BaseConfiguration(): this(defaultTableMap) { }

    public BaseConfiguration(string tableMap)
    {
        Map(x => x.ToTable(tableMap));

        var parm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), typeof(T).Name);
        var propExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>
            (Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(parm, "Id"), typeof(int)), parm);
        Property(propExpression).HasColumnName(typeof(T).Name + "_ID");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @AlexC, thanks for your reply. Really appreciated! I thought about that solution before, and I guess I would also have to include customPrimaryKeyMap as a parameter. So far no problem. However, there are some entities that need discrimination and that is why I would like a second mapping if possible. Please read my post as I will submit an edit. Also I will add the solution I have gotten so far. Feel free to add your comments as I am aware it might not be the best solution performance wise.